# Why my useState variable gives me undefine in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I made a custom node API which fetch the data of students from database.
And I connect it to react and try to fetch data and display. but I am facing an issue that I get data from API But when I try to set the data which I got from api response and try to console my `useState()` variable i.e. `apiData` it gives me undefined.

Below is my code:

```
const [apiData,setApiData] = useState([])
  const url ="http://localhost:5000/student/"

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetch(url).then(
      (response) =>{
        return response.json()
      }
    ).then((data) =>{
      console.log(data);
      setApiData(...data)
      console.log(apiData)
    })
  },[])
```

`console.log(data)` gives me `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

`console.log(apiData)` gives me `[]`

Comment: You expect the data to be available right away, while actually it requires a new render to access the data

Comment: can you please modify it

Comment: The answer by Lokesh should handle that. The additional useEffect triggers on every `apiData` change and should then log the data

Answer (score 1):

I believe this answers your question. [I’ve updated the state, but logging gives me the old value.](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value)

Calling the set function does not change state in the running code.  Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the `apiData` JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler.

Comment: when I remove my array dependency then it goes to infinite render

Answer (score 0):

```
    const [apiData,setApiData] = useState([])
      const url ="http://localhost:5000/student/"
     useEffect(() => {
if(apiData){
    console.log(apiData);
}
},[apiData])
      useEffect(() =>{
        fetch(url).then(
          (response) =>{
            return response.json()
          }
        ).then((data) =>{
          console.log(data);
          setApiData(...data)
          console.log(apiData)
        })
      },[])
```

Try writing your console.log in useEffect as shown above in the code.

Comment: still gives me an empty array

Comment: on the first render it will print empty array after the API call get success it will print the desired result if api returns any data

Answer (score 0):

In order to view/use a state value immediately after loading it/ changing its value, you need to use it inside the callback of the `set` hook.

Here, your state `apiData` was loaded with the value of `data` and you tried to access it immediately after it was set.

Also you are trying to spread an object array inside a state directly, which isn't right.

This is how you can preview the updated state: `setApiData(data, () => console.log('New Data values:'+apiData))`